# file not opens after if statement

Tags: python, file

I have a list of files from the database which need to opened one by one and write `Python is a great language.\nYeah its great!!` to all the files.

Problem:I cant open the file even the files are present.
`files` consists of:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

My code:

```
for files in cursor.fetchall():            
     sfile= files[1]
     if os.path.exists(os.path.join(path,sfile)): 
           with open(sfile,'r') as f:
                f.write( "Python is a great language.\nYeah its great!!\n");
                f.close()
```

Error:

```
    with open(sfile,'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.txt'
>>>
```

Please help me to rectify my error!

Comment: You're checking for `os.path.join(path,sfile)` but opening `sfile` (in `r`ead mode, too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the full path that you checked one line above. Also you need to open with `'w'` to write, `'r'` is for read. Also you don't need to `close` a file that you opened using `with`. Try this

```
for files in cursor.fetchall():            
     sfile= files[1]
     fullPath = os.path.join(path,sfile)
     if os.path.exists(fullPath ): 
           with open(fullPath ,'w') as f:
                f.write( "Python is a great language.\nYeah its great!!\n");
```

Comment: if i just wanted to read the file alone,I am getting the same error even after removing the write method. because my objective is to read the file alone.

Comment: If your objective is to only read, you shouldn't be writing to the file then