# text file is not read from a list of files

Tags: python, python-2.7, io

Not a duplicate of : [file not opens after if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470399/file-not-opens-after-if-statement)

I have a list of files from the database which need to opened one by one and read all the files.

Problem:I cant open and read the file even the files are present.
`files` consists of:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

My code:

```
path=r'C:\Python27' 
for files in cursor.fetchall():            
     sfile= files[1]
     if os.path.exists(os.path.join(path,sfile)): 
           with open(sfile,'r') as f:
                if 'cat' in f:
                    print 'meow'
```

Error:

```
    with open(sfile,'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.txt'
>>>
```

Please help me to rectify my error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to use `os.path.join` when you call `open` as you did for `os.path.exists`.

Also, you need to call `file.read` to get file content.

```
path = r'C:\Python27'  # NOTE: r'raw string literal': \ mean \ literally
for files in cursor.fetchall():            
     sfile = files[1]
     spath = os.path.join(path, sfile)
     if os.path.exists(spath):
         with open(spath) as f:
             if 'cat' in f.read():
                 print 'meow'
             # OR
             # if any('cat' in line for line in f):
             #     print 'meow'
```